# Null point exception when loading a 'raw' MediaPlayer resource in two activities

Tags: java, android, android-mediaplayer, android-resources

I am struggling with loading a sound in my application. I'm receiving a null point exception when trying to create the same "sound" in two activities. I have a variable clickSound that i declare in both activities which accesses the same Raw file. 
I have added a folder named 'raw' in the 'res' folder and the file clicksound.mp3 in it.

The thing is, for MainActivity is working perfect. for Second activity i just receive the exception.

Main Activity:

```
// Declare clickSound onCreate
        final MediaPlayer clickSound = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.click_button);
```

Second Activity:

```
private final MediaPlayer mClickSound = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.click_button);
```

The strange thing is that it worked some time ago but now i don't understand why not anymore. Any suggestions what is happening?

Comment: Add Logcat please!

Comment: You are referencing a file name called click_button inside raw, but you said the file name is clicksound.mp3.

Answer (score 0):

This line:

```
private final MediaPlayer mClickSound = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.click_button);`
```

for that moment the instace in not valid initialized, so **this** is not givin all that you need to create a media player.... move that to the `onCreate` method

Comment: Hi. I tried this but same problem. I am receiving the following error:
`android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/raw/click_button.mp3 from drawable resource ID #0x7f060000`

Answer (score 0):

I think this error is related when you don't initialize your class.

Try before something like this:

```
MediaPlayer mClickSound = new MediaPlayer();
```

Or full code:

```
private final MediaPlayer mClickSound;
//other things
MediaPlayer mClickSound = new MediaPlayer();
mClickSound = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.click_button);
```

It could be also that you're using two different names "clickSound" and "mClickSound"

Answer (score 0):

The problem was not with the MediaPlayer file. I had an error with my Json Reader that was not handling well an exception.